# How to associate a github package with another repo?

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, github-package-registry

So we made a mistake when defining our gemspec file for a ruby package which caused a large number of versions of our package to be associated with another private repository. I have read through the github packages docs and don't see a way to remove a package association from a private repository.

Our gem no longer builds with the updated gemspec file (pointing to the correct repository) as the package is already associated with another repository (the one in which we are trying to remove the association from).

Comment: This sounds like an issue for GitHub support.

Comment: @tadman Sent a message to their support. Will update once I get a response so that others in the same situation can find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If this is *private* repo/library, you can manually delete all versions of the package and it will remove the association of the package with that repo. Allowing you to then publish that package from another repo. I just did this on one of my work's private packages, so I can confirm.

Instructions on how to delete the versions are in the GitHub docs here: https://help.github.com/en/packages/publishing-and-managing-packages/deleting-a-package#deleting-a-version-of-a-private-package

Answer (score 0):

I received the following information from support for those of you who might be in the same situation.

`The only way for a user to free up that slot would be to delete the associated repository`

I hope that in the future Github will add the ability of change the association between a deployed gem and a private repository under the same organization.